# Python - no new object creation in generator

Tags: python, generator

Below a runnable codesnippet with behavior I cannot explain:
`name_generator` **should create** a new `LetterMan` object in each iteration, appends an arbitrary letter and yield it.

What happens is that on each iteration, a letter is somehow **appended** to the supposedly new object. The result of the script is:

```
class LetterMan(object):

    def __init__(self, name, letterlist=[]):
        self.letterlist = letterlist
        self.name = name

    def add_letter(self, letter):
        self.letterlist.append(letter)


def name_generator():
    for name in ["Andrew", "Bryan", "Casey"]:
        l = LetterMan(name)
        l.add_letter(name[-1])
        yield l


if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = name_generator()
    for lman in n:
        print lman.name, lman.letterlist



# Andrew ['w'] 
# Bryan ['w', 'n'] 
# Casey ['w', 'n', 'y']
```

I am expecting:

```
# Andrew ['w']
# Bryan ['n']
# Casey ['y']
```

Is it some sort of optimization?
Why is there no new object created on each iteration?
How would I achieve the expected result?

I already tried deleting the object after each `yield` with no result

I am using python `2.7.3` on ubuntu

Comment: You can avoid this behavior by having `letterlist` default to `None` and then assign to it an empty list in the function body if it is `None`. That way, the empty list is created *when* the function is executed, not before.

Comment: Thanks @Blender (Both for the solution and for the reference)